# PostgreSQL, import a csv file

Tags: postgresql, csv

I'm trying to copy a CSV file into an empty table, after trying to match the columns in the CSV which failed with the exact same error.

```
COPY books 
FROM '/path/to/file/books.csv' CSV HEADER;
```

error:

```
ERROR:  extra data after last expected column
CONTEXT:  COPY books, line 2: "1,Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince (Harry Potter  #6),J.K. Rowling/Mary GrandPré,4.57,0439785..."
SQL state: 22P04
```

Also, I would like that the publication_date will be of date type, so it can be queried, How can that be applied during copying?

a piece of the CSV file:

```
bookID| title        | authors  |   average_rating  | isbn|isbn13 |num_pages  | ratings_count| text_reviews_count| publication_date|
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1     | harry potter |          |                   |             |
      |(harry Potter |          |                   |             |
      |     #6)      | author   | 4                 |"num" | "num"| 600       | 3243         | 534                | 01/01/2000    |
```

```
SELECT * FROM books

output:

bookID| title    | authors  |   average_rating |    isbn   |isbn13| language_code    
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
text  | character| text     | integer        | text   | text  |  character |      
      |  varying |          |                |        |       |  varying               

| num_pages  | ratings_count| text_reviews_count| publication_date| publisher
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| integer    | bigint       | bigint            | date            |  character
                                                                     varying
```

Comment: can you add your structure of table books?

Comment: It's empty, I also tried adding columns manually but ended but with the same error.

Comment: You Must have the same columns that the csv file

Comment: It raises the same error, will edit the post.

Comment: Ok, try put DDL of table books and a part of csv file in text, no image please

Comment: Did my best adding tables

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the columns number mismatch from `CSV` file and `TABLE`, but you can specify via `COPY` command the columns for the table that you need:

```
  COPY books (bookID,title,authors,average_rating,isbn,isbn13,num_pages,ratings_count , text_reviews_count , publication_date) FROM '/path/to/file/books.csv' CSV header delimiter ',';
```

You can specify you delimiter